# For a pandas CategoricalDtype, can I set ordering with a function (and not an ordered collection)?

Tags: pandas

I'm aware that one can create a `CategoricalDtype` like

```
CategoricalDtype(["a", "b", "c"], ordered=True)
```

My question is, can one specify ordering with a function that returns a sort key?

This is how `sort_index` works for example:

```
df.sort_index(axis=0, key=lambda index: index.map(convert_index_value_to_sort_key))
```

Asking because sometimes I don't know the categories ahead of time, but I still want to define how ordering should work.

Comment: *sometimes I don't know the categories ahead of time*. When you use `astype(mycat)`, you already know all categories... So you can create the ordered values before.

Comment: If you don't know the categories ahead of time, then your data should not be of categorical type...

Comment: I deal with data where categories come and go with time, and I concatenate dataframes that might have different values for a categorical column. I am aware I can inspect unique values ahead of time and provide a sorted collection to the constructor... I'm just wondering if there's support for something like a "dynamic enum" like exists in other applications, where the dtype maintains a set of observed values and automatically handles encoding for me. It sounds like this functionality is not implemented in pandas.CategoricalDtype.